# We toss coin until we get $2$ times in a row same symbol (head or tails).

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We toss coin until we get $2$ times in a row same symbol (head or tails). Task is to model the probability space and to calculate probability of ending experiment in even number of tossing.

I defined $ \Omega = \{ TT, THH, THTT, THTHH, ... , HH, HTT, HTHH, HTHTT, ... \} $ $ A = \{ TT, THTT, ... , HH, HTHH, ... \}  $ , $A\subset \Omega$. Since $ A $ has all elements that are different from each other I was planning to calculate probability of each element of $A$ and add all those together, but I got stuck on calculating cardinal number of $\Omega $ .

Comment: If you first get two consecutive like symbols on toss $n,$ then the first $n-1$ symbols must alternate.

Answer (score 0):

You must sum until infinity:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(n=2k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{2^{2k-1}}=\frac23.$$

Comment: What about the modelling of the probability space ?

Comment: @Peter, the OP defined them well enough. Now the probability is $P(n=2)=P(TT)+P(HH)=\frac12$, $P(n=4)=P(THTT)+P(HTHH)=\frac1{2^3}$, etc.